# how to create simple voting app like hot or not for android

Tags: android, mobile-application

I was looking for some tutorial or any opensource implementation of simple vote up / vote down any pic on android. Something similar to hot or not.

Can you please tell me how can i implement it?. Should i keep the up/down button constant and change the pic or whole activity needs to be changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change the activity. Just implement ImageView. When a vote has been made, simply change the picture in the ImageView. `setImageResource(R.drawable.something);` or an image file from storage. EDIT: The votes can be stored in Preferences.

Comment: true but now i want to record the vote for each image. So should i maintain a reference for each image with some id? or there is any other way.

Comment: You can use Android's built in Sql lite database to store image id and votes.

Comment: nice have you seen any sample app or example.

Comment: a sample voting app, no ... but I made an app that stores gps data to Sql lite database.